# python ruayaml dump parameter instructions

Tags: yaml

from the docs here: https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detail.html#indentation-of-block-sequences

given

```
x:
- b: 1
- 2
```

then they say

> The above example with the often seen yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2) indentation:

```
x:
  y:
    - b: 1
    - 2
```

where did `y` come from?

Comment: It's just an example of `mapping=2` spacing before a nested element (the y)... I'd suggest filing a docs issue on the repo since those aren't equivalent documents

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry - i mean, how did that y come out of the original yaml? it says "using the above example"

Comment: It didn't. The example is only showing the indent function with two spaces before "nested `y` mapping", and 4 spaces before the sequence that that maps to), not "using the above". It could say "updating the above example", but again, that's a documentation issue.. Calling `indent` function isn't adding sections

Comment: I suggest asking here - https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/tickets/